# Using pointers to pointers to update linked lists in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, function-definition

I am currently working through C Programming A Modern Approach by K.N. King, and one of the exercise questions is:

The following function is supposed to insert a new node into its proper place in an ordered list, returning a pointer to the first node in the modified list. Unfortunately, the function doesn't word correctly in all cases. Explain what's wrong with it and show how to fix it. Assume that the node structure is the one defined in Section 17.5.

```
struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node next;
};

struct node *insert_into_ordered_list(struct node *list, struct node *new_node)
{
    struct node *cur = list, *prev = NULL;
    while (cur->value <= new_node->value) {
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    prev->next = new_node;
    new_node->next = cur;
    return list;
}
```

After trying to understand this for a while and struggling, I eventually came across another stackoverflow question where someone posted this as their answer.
I currently don't  have enough reputation to ask about it on there, so I'm asking here to try to wrap my head around this.

```
struct node * insert_into_ordered_list( struct node *list, struct node *new_node )
{
    struct node **pp = &list;

    while ( *pp != NULL && !( new_node->value < ( *pp )->value ) ) 
    {
        pp = &( *pp )->next;
    }

    new_node->next = *pp;
    *pp = new_node;

    return list;
}
```

Could someone explain to me how the previous node, the one before the inserted new_node is being updated to point at the inserted new_node? I'm guessing the line `*pp = new_node;` has something to do with it, but I can't understand how. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, `pp` is a pointer to the pointer to the "current node in the position in the list" - this is sometimes called a "handler" in the literature. The name `pp` comes from "pointer to pointer".

`*` is the "dereference operator", specifically it means "the data at", so `*pp` means "the data at memory location pp," which in this case is the actual pointer to the current node.

When you use an assignment operator with a derefernce, you are saying set the data at memory location `pp` to `new_node` (that data happens to also be a pointer). Remember, `new_node` is a pointer to your new node's data. So when you run the line:

```
new_node->next = *pp;
```

you are setting the "next" entry in the data at new_node equal to the pointer to the "current" node. Then when you run the line:

```
*pp = new_node;
```

you are updating the pointer at location pp to point to the structured data in `struct node` format at `new_node`.

Sometimes when unwrapping all these pointers and dereferences in C, **it helps me to make sure I understand the *type of every expression and subexpression***.

For example here are various expressions above, and their types, expressed as boolean operations in modern C using the `typeof` operator. Note that in a real program, at compile time these will be replaced with the value `1` ("truthy" in C) :)

```
typeof(new_node) == struct node *;
typeof(pp) == struct node **;
typeof(*pp) == struct node *;
typeof(*new_node) = struct node;
```

Note that since in C, the `=` operator causes memory to be copied to cause the left side of the expression to be equal to the right side in any future evaluations (commonly referred to as the `lvalue` and the `rvalue` of the expression). So in the parlance, After an `=` the `lvalue` could evaluate differently than before. The `rvalue` is used for calculating the new value of the `lvalue`, but itself remains unmodified after the assignment operation.

It is important to remember, anytime you use `=` you are blowing over any data in the `lvalue`. This is often confusing, as `=` is the **ONLY** operator in C that causes "side-effects" (Sometimes `()` is also considered an operator, of course function calls can also cause side-effects, as in this example using a pointer argument to the function and dereferencing it within the function body).

**ALL** other operators simply evaluate inside expressions (for example, `*`, `&`, `+` etc.), but when you use `=` it makes changes. For example, any given expression containing the `lvalue` or anything dependent on the `lvalue` might evaluate to a different value before and after an `=` operation. Because functions can have pointer arguments as in this example, function calls can also cause side effects.

You can also, more simply, think of `*` as an operator that "removes `*`'s" from types, and `&` as an operator that "adds `*`'s" to types - as above they are called the dereference and reference operator.

Comment: so `*pp = new_node;` is replacing the current node with new_node, but since new_node's "next" entry points to what was the current node, it's not lost, and allows the linked list to still be connected? Does this replacement replace the pointer in the previous node's "next" entry by swapping the address that used to be there with new_nodes?

Comment: It doesn't NEED to replace the pointer in the previous node's entry, because that pointer still points to the same location: the one that used to be occupied by **pp, which is now occupied by *new_node  !! That's the whole point of "sliding" the data at new_node into *pp, any existing pointers to that location will dereference to the data inside new_node in the future. Coding is beautiful, no?

Answer (score 1):

`pp` either initially points to the pointer `head` or due to the while loop to the data member `next` of some node

```
while ( *pp != NULL && !( new_node->value < ( *pp )->value ) ) 
{
    pp = &( *pp )->next;
}
```

For example if `pp` points to `head`. If `head` is equal to `NULL` or `new_node->value < head->value` then these statements

```
new_node->next = *pp;
*pp = new_node;
```

in fact are equivalent to

```
new_node->next = head;
head = new_node
```

If `pp` points to the data member `next` of some node then these statements

```
new_node->next = *pp;
*pp = new_node;
```

change the value of the of the current data member `next` with the address of the new node

```
*pp = new_node;
```

and before this the data member `next` of the new node is set to the value stored in the data member `next` of the current node.

As for this function

```
struct node *insert_into_ordered_list(struct node *list, struct node *new_node)
{
    struct node *cur = list, *prev = NULL;
    while (cur->value <= new_node->value) {
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    prev->next = new_node;
    new_node->next = cur;
    return list;
}
```

then there is no check whether the pointer `cur` becomes (or initially is) equal to `NULL`. And secondly the pointer `list` is not changed when the new node is inserted before the node pointed to by `list`.

The function could be defined the following way

```
struct node *insert_into_ordered_list(struct node *list, struct node *new_node)
{
    if ( list == NULL || new_node->value < list->value )
    {
        new_node->next = list;
        list = new_node;
    }
    else
    { 
        struct node *cur = list;
        while ( cur->next != NULL && cur->next->value <= new_node->value) 
        {
            cur = cur->next;
        }
    
        new_node->next = cur->next;
        cur->next = new_node;
    }

    return list;
}
```